# How include SVG picture in a table latex?

Tags: svg, latex, pdflatex

I have a problem to insert multiple SVG pictures in a table. I try many ways with tabular but I don't have any succes.

I manage to implement a single picture in the document with this piece of code, using the inkscape method:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{5cm}
    \input{SupplyChain.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

I would like a table with 3 rows and 2 columns. The first column contains the picture and the second its description.

Comment: please make a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same code in a tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\def\svgwidth{5cm}
\input{test.pdf_tex}
&
text\\
\def\svgwidth{5cm}
\input{test.pdf_tex}
&
text\\   
\def\svgwidth{5cm}
\input{test.pdf_tex}
&
text\\   
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```